# «Мене звуть» чи «Мене звати»?

Tags: вживання-слів

Зустрічав обидві форми - і «звуть», і «звати». Хотілося б дізнатися, яка з них є правильною. Можливо, це просто два паралельні варіанти, кожен з яких є коректним?

Comment: Вітаємо на сайті Ukrainian Language.SE! Будь ласка, почитайте про [наші критерії](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/), за якими ми оцінюємо хороші питання. Зверніть увагу на пункт 4: на нашому сайті заохочується спроба самостійного дослідження, було б добре, якби ви у наступних питаннях писали трішки про те, що саме ви знайшли самостійно, і чому ви досі вагаєтесь. Ви завжди можете виправити свій допис за допомогою посилання [edit]. Поки що саме нехтування самостійним дослідженням заважає мені підтримувати ваші питання стрілочкою вгору.

Comment: В українській мові дієслова в неозначеній формі самостійно, зазвичай, не вживаються, тільки поряд із іншим дієсловом. Тож форма "Мене звати" мала б бути неправильною. В ній є упущене дієслово "Є". Мене Є звати... Але "Є" упускається і в інших ситуаціях. (після частки "це" до прикладу перше, що спадає на думку...) Тож нема біди. Упускати "Є" - це вже мовна традиція :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

У корпусі [ГРАК](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8)-4:

- [«мене/тебе/його/її звати»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/sortx?q=aword,(%22[%D0%9C%D0%BC]%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%22|%22[%D0%A2%D1%82]%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%22|%22[%D0%99%D0%B9]%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%22|%22[%D0%87%D1%97]%D1%97%22)+%22%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%22&q=e100&corpname=grac4&sattr=doc.date) — 3200 траплянь (зокрема Квітка-Основ'яненко, Шевченко, Марко Вовчок, Куліш й інші);
- [«мене/тебе/його/її звуть»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/sortx?q=aword,(%22[%D0%9C%D0%BC]%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%22|%22[%D0%A2%D1%82]%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%22|%22[%D0%99%D0%B9]%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%22|%22[%D0%87%D1%97]%D1%97%22)+%22%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%22&q=e100&corpname=grac4&sattr=doc.date) — 2505 траплянь (зокрема Квітка-Основ'яненко, Нечуй-Левицький, Леся Українка, Марко Вовчок й інші).

По-моєму, обидва варіанти цілком правильні.

Comment: @Sasha також хочу зазначити, що ГРАК-4 - це, все ж таки, загальний вжиток, тож було б добре підкріпити дані з ГРАКу чимось ще.

Comment: @P. Vowk, Sasha, Дякую за поради. На сайті я новачок, тому, на жаль, не знаю багатьох аспектів. Відповіді прийняв (відверто кажучи, навіть не знав про наявність галочки ). Радий, що є люди, готові підказати.

Comment: @Михайло завжди раді! Наснаги вам.

Answer (score 1):

У Російсько-українському словнику сталих виразів 1959 р. Виргана, Пилинської [є таке](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/search.php?fullname=%E7%E2%E0%F2%FC&submit=%D8%F3%EA%E0%F2%E8):

> *Как тебя, вас… зовут?* – як тебе, вас звуть (кличуть)?; як ти звешся?; як ви зветеся?; як тебе, вас на ім’я (на ймення)?; (іноді) як на тебе, на вас кажуть?

Варіанту зі «звати» немає.